# Язык python. Как запустить синк функцию, пока спит event_loop

Tags: python, асинхронность

Допустим у меня есть следующий код:

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, sleep


async def coro():
    await sleep(5)
    print('I`m end work')


def func():
    print('I`m toje end work')


main_loop = get_event_loop()

main_loop.run_until_complete(coro())
func()

main_loop.run_forever()
```

Его проблема заключается в том, что пока main_loop спит (Он ждёт завершение sleep) в коде ничего не происходит, а хотелось бы что бы во время сна программа выполнила функцию func().

Каким образом это можно реализовать, не прибегая к использованию threading и multiprocessing?

Comment: Можно нескромный вопрос - а зачем?

Comment: @andreymal. У меня есть длительные асинхронные методы, которые я намереваюсь использовать при разработке сайта на django. И пока у меня допустим идёт какой либо слип, я бы хотел не просто в тупую занимать мейн поток, а делать какие либо действия по мимо слипа

Comment: Django поддерживает асинхронщину. Если вы будете использовать ASGI, то мейн поток будет не простаивать, а обрабатывать другие запросы. Есть подозрение, что вы решаете какую-то несуществующую проблему